# make and access object like eloquent object laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have a code User::find(0) that will find and return data of first user in database type object. I can set the value like $user->name = "Name 1" or $user->name = "Name 2".

> "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

I made a new variable like $teacher = (object) [] and $teacher = new \stdClass. I can set the value like $teacher->name = "Teacher 1". But, I will get above error if I set it like $teacher['name'] = "Teacher 1".

> Expected type "object". Found string[].

So, I tried to make $teacher = array() and $teacher = []; I can set the value like $teacher['name'] = "Teacher 1", but I will get above error if I set it with $teacher->name = "Teacher 2".

So, I'm confused why User::find(0) object can be set using '->' and '[]'. I'm still learning to use documentation. I spent alot of time but still can't find it even in another website. Can you you tell me how can I make the same object like User::find(0) that I can set the value using '->' and '[]'?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `User` model extends the Laravel base model `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php`. The base model implements the `ArrayAccess` interface which allows accessing objects as arrays.

You can read more on this in the docs from php itself
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php